# Achieve "npm run x" behavior without a "scripts" entry?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line-interface

To run a node command within the "context" of your installed `node_modules`, you can make an entry in the `scripts` field of `package.json`.  Eg:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --recursive test/**/*.js --compilers js:babel-register"
  }
...
```

and then I can type `npm run test` in my project root, and the mocha tests will run (by calling the mocha binary installed in `node_modules/mocha/bin`).

Is there a way to achieve precisely the same behavior but without creating a scripts entry?  Eg, for a one-off "script"?

I'm imagining something like the following, as an equivalent to `npm run test`:

```
npm cmd mocha --recursive test/**/*.js --compilers js:babel-register
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

NOTE: I should clarify that I'm looking for true equivalence.  That is, my command should be able to access other script commands, etc.  I know you can always call the binaries using node and the path to the binary within node_modules, but that's not an adequate solution.

Comment: there isn't a specific use case.  The use case is I want to do something that I can do in package scripts but it's a one off and I don't want to put an entry in scripts.  it's come up on a number of occasions and I wanted a general solution.  say you ask me for help with your project and I pull it down and I want to want run one of the binaries in it. Saying that I should install it globally especially when it might not be something I even want installed globally and when it's already installed in your project seems misguided

Answer (score 39, accepted):

<sup>Note: This answer addresses the OP's specific use case: calling the CLIs of *dependent packages in the context of a given project*; it is *not* about making CLIs *globally available* - see bottom for a discussion.</sup>

**tl;dr:**

**On *Unix*-like platforms**, **prepend `npm run env --` to your command**; e.g.:

```
npm run env -- mocha --recursive test/**/*.js --compilers js:babel-register
```

This **not only enables calling of dependent CLIs by mere name, but fully replicates the environment that `npm` sets** behind the scenes when you use `npm test` or `npm run-script <script-defined-in-package.json>`.

Sadly, this approach doesn't work on Windows.

For Windows solutions, convenience aliases (including once-per-session environment-configuration commands), and background information, read on.

---

There are two (not mutually exclusive) **approaches to making an npm project's dependencies' CLIs callable by mere name from the shell**:

- (a) Use a ***per-invocation* helper command that you pass your commands to**.
- (b) Run a ***once-per-session* command that (temporarily) modifies your environment**.

[Frxstrem's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39990838/45375) provides an *incomplete* solution for (a) on Unix-like platforms; it *may*, however, be sufficient, depending on your specific needs.
It is incomplete in that it merely prepends the directory containing (symlinks to) the dependent CLIs to the `$PATH`, without performing all other environment modifications that happen when you invoke `npm test` or `npm run-script <script-defined-in-package.json`.

---

### Unix convenience and Windows solutions

Note that **all solutions below are based on `npm run env`**, which ensures that all necessary environment variables are set, just as they are when your run scripts predefined in the project's `package.json` file with `npm test` or `npm run-script <script>`.
These environment modifications include:

- Prepending `$(npm prefix -g)/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin` and the project directory's `./node_modules/.bin` subdirectory, which is where symlinks to the dependencies' CLIs are located, (temporarily) to the `$PATH` environment variable.
- Defining numerous `npm_*` environment variables that reflect the project's settings, such as `npm_package_version` as well as the `npm` / `node` environment.

---

#### Convenience solutions for Unix-like platforms:

Both solutions below are ***alias*-based**, which in the case of (a) is a more light-weight alternative to using a *script*, and in the case of (b) is a prerequisite to allow modification of the current shell's environment (although a shell function could be used too).

For convenience, **add these aliases to your shell profile/initialization 
file**.

**(a) Per-invocation helper:**

Defining

```sh
alias nx='npm run-script env --'
```

allows you to invoke your commands ad-hoc simply by prepending `nx`; e.g.:

```sh
nx mocha --recursive test/**/*.js --compilers js:babel-register
```

**(b) Once-per-session configuration command:**

```sh
alias npmenv='npm run env -- $SHELL'
```

Run `npmenv` to enter a *child shell* with the the npm environment set, allowing direct (by-name-only) invocation of dependent CLIs in that child shell.
In other words, use this as follows:

```sh
cd ~/some-npm-project
npmenv # after this, you can run dependent CLIs by name alone; e.g., `mocha ...`
# ... run your project-specific commands
exit  # exit the child shell before you switch to a different project
```

---

#### Windows solutions:

**(a) *and* (b)**: Note that Windows (unlike POSIX-like shells on Unix-like platforms) doesn't (directly) support passing environment variables scoped to a single command only, so the commands below, even when passed a specific command to execute (case (a)), invariably also modify the session's environment (case (b)).

**PowerShell** (also works in the Unix versions):

Add the following function to your `$PROFILE` (user-specific profile script):

```sh
function npmenv($commandIfAny) {
  npm run env -- |
    ? { $_ -and $_ -notmatch '^>' -and $_ -match '^[a-z_][a-z0-9_]+=' } | 
      % { $name, $val = $_ -split '='; set-item -path "env:$name" -value $val }
  if ($?) {
    if ($commandIfAny) {
      & $commandIfAny $Args
    }
  } 
}
```

**`cmd.exe` (regular command prompt, often mistakenly called the "DOS prompt"):**

Create a batch file named `npmenv.cmd`, place it in a folder in your `%PATH%`, and define it as follows:

```sh
@echo off
:: Set all environment variables that `npm run env` reports.
for /f "delims==; tokens=1,*" %%i in ('npm run env ^| findstr /v "^>"') do set "%%i=%%j"
:: Invoke a specified command, if any.
%*
```

**Usage** (both `cmd.exe` and PowerShell):

For use case (b), invoke simply as `npmenv` *without arguments*; after that, you can call dependent CLIs by mere name (`mocha ...`).

For use case (a), prepend `npmenv` to your command; e.g.:

```sh
 npmenv mocha --recursive test/**/*.js --compilers js:babel-register
```

Caveat: As noted, the *first* invocation of `npmenv` - whether with or without arguments -  invariably modifies the `%PATH%` / `$env:PATH` variable for the remainder of the session.

If you switch to a different project in the same session, be sure to run `npmenv` (at least once) again, but note that this prepends *additional* directories to `%PATH%`, so you you could still end up accidentally running a previous project's executable if it isn't an installed dependency of the now-current project.

From PowerShell, you could actually *combine* the two solutions to get distinct (a) and (b) functionality after all: define the `*.cmd` file above as a distinct command (using a different name such as `nx.cmd`) that you only use *with arguments* (a), and redefine the PowerShell function to serve as the argument-less environment modification-only complement (b).
This works, because PowerShell invariably runs `*.cmd` files in a *child* process that cannot affect the current PowerShell session's environment.

---

**Notes on the scope of the question and this answer:**

The OP's question is about calling the CLIs of *already-installed dependent packages in the context of a given project* ad-hoc, by mere executable name - just as `npm` allows you to do in the commands added to the `scripts` key in the `package.json` file.

The question is *not* about making CLIs *globally available* (by installing them with `npm install -g`).

In fact, if you want to author modular, self-contained packages, do *not* depend on globally installed packages. Instead, make all dependent packages *part of your project*: use `npm install --save` (for runtime dependencies) and `npm install --save-dev` (for development time-only dependencies) - see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

In particular, if a given CLI is already installed as a *dependency*, installing it globally *as well* (potentially a different version) is not only redundant, but asking for confusion over which version is executed when.

Answer (score 3):

I've saved this little script as `~/bin/npm-cmd` on my computer:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
PATH="$(npm bin):$PATH" "$@"
```

Then running `npm-cmd PROGRAM …ARGS` should look for `PROGRAM` in `./node_modules/.bin` first, before falling back to normal lookup.

Comment: This is a pragmatic, but incomplete solution, which, however, will probably still work in many cases. 
It is incomplete, because it only partially replicates the environment that `npm` sets when `npm test` or `npm run-script` are invoked: 
`npm` not only prepends an additional folder to the `$PATH`, but also sets numerous `npm_*` environment variables based on the `package.json` contents and the npm / Node.js environment; `npm run env` shows the complete environment.

Answer (score 2):

Npx should serve the purpose which is bundled with npm in the recent versions (>5.2.0).

`npx <command>`

Check this [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) for more details. It has options like --no-install which maybe required to keep its behaviour more similar to npm.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: This answer works on all platforms.</sup>

`npm i -g mocha`

`mocha --recursive test/**/*.js --compilers js:babel-register`

[Mocha CLI documentation](https://mochajs.org/) (scroll to usage section).

---

If you want to run an **npm** package as an executable from the CLI, the right way to do it is via the package.json **[bin](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin)** entry. It allows you to map files in your project as executables. The first line of the files, like normal scripts should start with a [shebang](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), `#!/usr/bin/env node` if it's a node script.

By mapping these files in your package.json bin, you will be able to call them from other packages scripts section, or call them from the cli when your package is installed globally with `npm install -g <package>`. The *bin* node can be an object that maps script names to script files within your project if you want to add multiple scripts to your path as executables, or a string path of a single file that you would like to act as the executable for your package.

This is in fact the [exact same mechanism](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/package.json) used by mocha in your example:

[image: mocha bin]

Without this, mocha would never be in your path when installing it globally, and would not be accessible via your scripts section.

Comment: The `bin` key describes the project's _own_ executables (what executables to "export" when the project itself is _installed_). By contrast, this question is about calling the CLIs of the project's _dependencies_, which are symlinked into the `./node_modules/.bin` subdirectory, while _developing_ a package.

Comment: If you would like to call mocha from cli, many a node expert would disagree with your approach. The correct way to do it is `npm i -g mocha`. The purpose of this is to do what this question is asking, add mocha as an executable in your path.  That works because mocha is marked in the bin section of its own package.json. Relying on the method you're suggesting will not hold up at all cross platform.

Comment: It's true that my approach only works on Unix-like platforms (I've added a note), but that's a separate issue. The OP wants to call the CLIs of existing dependencies of a given project directly from the shell by name only, whatever they may be. Reinstalling the dependencies globally is not only heavy-handed but is asking for trouble down the road (and, as stated, the `bin` key serves a different purpose).

Comment: This is actually the *exact* purpose that bin is meant to serve - adding scripts as executables to your path (path context is denoted by whether or not you pass the global flag, omitting adds to the path within your projects scripts, and passing adds to your shell). Using `npm i -g` on a package that is meant to be added to your path is no more heavy handed than adding an alias to it in your bash profile. If you don't want it in your path anymore, the resolution is simple `npm rm -g mocha`.

Comment: No, the `bin` key is not meant to help you invoke the CLIs of your package's _dependencies_, it is there to define the CLIs that your package _implements_ (exports). A package's dependencies, including their CLIs, are installed in subtree `node_modules`, which is where `npm run` finds them when they're referenced by name only in tasks defined in the `scripts` key. The OP's question is about how to have the same convenience of invocation directly in the shell, without needing to use predefined tasks and `npm run`.

Comment: The canonical answer to that question is `npm i -g mocha`. I am merely explaining the many ways *bin* can be used in case the OP perhaps wants to extend his CLI with some of his own scripts.

Comment: `npm i -g mocha` not only needlessly changes the global environment, it also doesn't make sure that the same version that is embedded in the project is installed. To achieve what the OP wants with global installations, you'd have to (a) examine the `package.json` to determine the specific version numbers of the dependent packages with CLIs and then globally install those specific versions, and (b) you'd have to repeat that process every time you switch to a different project - a fragile & cumbersome solution. The `bin` key information is unrelated to the question and therefore a distraction.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're now using `pnpm`, its equivalent of `npm env` is `pnpm exec`. So you might run `pnpm exec -- mocha --recursive test/**/*.js --compilers js:babel-register`.

See https://pnpm.io/cli/exec