# Run npm scripts locally using terminal

Tags: npm, package.json

Is there a way to run npm scripts that have only been installed using `--save-dev` using the terminal? Currently, I add a script to the `scripts` section within the `package.json` and then run `npm run myscriptname`. This works, but is there a more direct way without the entry in `package.json`?

**EDIT**:

In my example I use `lerna` to multiple packaging. To initialize the `lerna repository` the following steps are necessary:

```
mkdir LernaProject
cd LernaProject
git init
npm init
npm install lerna --save-dev
```

Now I want to run `lerna init`, but I don't know how or if it is possible to run that directly due to my local install with `--save-dev` and not with `-g`. Hence, I add an entry in the `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "lerna:init": "lerna init"
  }
  ...
}
```

And then I run that entry:

```
npm run lerna:init
```

Comment: I don't quite get the -1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily found it out myself, read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39990788/achieve-npm-run-x-behavior-without-a-scripts-entry).

```
npm run env lerna init
```

This though does not work on Windows. Only tested on Linux. Probably also works on a Mac.

---

Another way to do the same is to use `npx` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100667/install-dependencies-using-lerna-fails).

```
npx lerna init
```

Answer (score 0):

if you create package.json(npm init is easiest way) and then install dependecies they will be saved in package.json.If you want install all dependecies from package.json you can run npm install. You need define scripts so you can run them.

Answer (score 0):

Using `npx` instead of `npm` will be the easier option.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77398078/15285113

This answer explains it better.