# Install dependencies using lerna fails

Tags: lerna

I am trying to add a module as dev-dependency from npm to one of several modules I have in my lerna repo, but when doing that neither is the module added to only one of my modules, nor is it added as a dev-dependency. Instead it is added to all of my local modules and it also is added as a normal dependency.

I have created the following:

```
mkdir FirstProject
cd FirstProject
yarn init
yarn add lerna --dev
npm run env lerna init
mkdir packages/one
mkdir packages/two
cd packages/one
yarn init
cd ../..
cd packages/two
yarn init
cd ../..
```

I now have the following tree structure:

```
myuser@mylaptop:~/FirstProject$ tree -I node_modules
.
├── lerna.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── one
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── two
│       └── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

Both, `packages/one/package.json` and `packages/two/package.json` look alike (except the name field):

```
{
  "name": "one",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

If I now try to install a new `devDependency` in `packages/one`, i.e. `angular`, I could `cd packages/one` and then `yarn add angular --dev`.

But as suggested in the [lerna documentation](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#add) there is a `lerna add` command that is supposed to do exactly that. The command to do exactly the above is supposed to be the following:

```
npm run env lerna add angular --scope=one --dev
```

But, now both `packages/one/package.json` and `packages/two/package.json` look again alike (except the name field) and the entry was made as a `dependency` and not as a `devDependency`:

```
{
  "name": "one",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.10"
  }
}
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

Just in case this matters:

- lerna version `2.11.0`
- npm version `5.8.0`
- yarn version `1.6.0`
- node version `v9.11.1`
- Work environment `Ubuntu 16.04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mention the missing last step of `lerna init` to create `lerna.json` :-)

Anyhow, try with npm>5.2:

```
npx lerna add angular --scope=one --dev
```

> npx --help: Execute binaries from npm packages.

or the manual execution of the binary:

```
./node_modules/.bin/lerna add angular --scope=one --dev
```

And I do have the resulting:

```
{
  "name": "one",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope, didn't forget `lerna init`. Did that with the command `npm run env lerna init` (see in first code section below `yarn add lerna --dev`).

Comment: Ok, just followed your advice with `npx` and it works. Seems there are difficulties with `npm run env ...`. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I see, sorry about that. But anyhow, it should work as I explained with `npx` or `node_modules/.bin`. It adds it as a dependency when using `npm run env`

Answer (score 0):

@Socrates, just so you know the answer to this mistery is very simple. `npm run` ignores all `--something` parameters unless you add a lonely -- before those arguments.

`bash
npm run lerna add angular -- --scope=one --dev`

you could have used the following command since you ar eusing yarn anyway:
`bash
yarn lerna add angular --scope=one --dev`